# Python pathlib.Path library always cuts last folder from the path and adds it to the name of created file

Tags: python, xml, path, pathlib

So here is the problem, I have some path which is like this:

```
get_path = 'C:/Users/user1/Desktop/Files/File/1/category/UFF/'
```

Then I use this to "make" it win path:

```
path = pathlib.Path(get_path)
```

So now every time I use it, to create some other files inside of path directory, my files are created inside of "category" folder with prefix UFF, so file names are:

```
category folder:

UFFNameFile1.xml
UFFNameFile2.xml
```

instead of

```
UFF folder:

NameFile1.xml
NameFile2.xml
```

For creation of files I use:

```
tree.write(str(path)+name+'.xml', encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

Anyone has idea what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last slash in `get_path` is dropped when passing to `Path`.  The string you are passing to `tree.write` is exactly what you are seeing: `'C:/Users/user1/Desktop/Files/File/1/category/UFFsomefilename.XML'`

You can fix this as followed:

```
path_out = path / f'{name}.xml'
tree.write(path_out.as_posix(), encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

Comment: Man thanks a lot, this solves my issue! Still cannot understand why last slash is dropped in this case, but it works!